# I cant get out of my while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

The following program i wrote for a class activity to prompt the user for a infinite amount of test marks between 0 - 100 and when a user enters a mark outside that range it should tell the user that its invalid(which works so far in my program). When the user enters "-1" its should stop the program and then print out the average of those marks.

```
import java.util.*; 

public class HmWk62 {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int count=1; 
        int mark, total=0; 
        double average; 

        System.out.println("please enter mark "+count);
        mark = console.nextInt();
        count++; 

        while ((mark >= 0)&&(mark <= 100)){
            System.out.println("Please enter mark "+count);
            mark = console.nextInt(); 
            total += mark ;
            ++count; 

            while ((mark < 0)||(mark > 100)){
                System.out.println("Invalid mark, please re-enter");
                mark = console.nextInt(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd sugged a ```do { /* ask for input and proceed if 0-100 */... } while (/* check input is not -1 */);``` loop better

Comment: Have you tired to debug your code ?

Comment: You can use demorgan's laws to prove that the condition of the inner while loop is the  negation of the condition of the outer loop. That means once you enter the outer loop your program is doomed to run until it's killed (since after the inner while loop it's condition is `false` and therefore the condition of the outer loop is `true`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When the user enters "-1" its should stop the program and then print out the average of those marks.

Well if the user enters -1, you'll never get out of the *nested* loop that validates the input.

If you want to allow -1, you should changed the condition in the nested loop to allow it:

```
while (mark < -1 || mark > 100)
```

Also note that you're *using* the value of `mark` before you validate it - so if you enter 10000, you'll still add 10000 to `total` before you then ask for a new value - and you'll then ignore the new value.

Also, you're not using the first value of `mark` entered at all, other than to see whether or not you should enter the loop.

I suspect you actually want something like:

```
while (true) {
    int mark = readMark(scanner, count);
    if (mark == -1) {
        break;
    }
    count++;
    total += mark;
}
// Now print out the average, etc

...

private static int readMark(Scanner scanner, int count) {
    System.out.println("Please enter mark " + count);
    while (true) {
        int mark = scanner.nextInt();
        if (mark >= -1 && mark <= 100) {
            return mark;
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid mark, please re-enter");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your code check if a global variable is set.

For instance, create the variable: `boolean userCancelled = false;`

in the while loop check this variable:
like:

```
while (userCancelled  != false && (mark >= 0)&&(mark <= 100))
{
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you replace the `while` loop with this `do while loop` as below:

```
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter mark "+count);
        mark = console.nextInt(); 
        if(mark == -1){
           break;
        }else if((mark >= 0)&&(mark <= 100)){
           total += mark ;
           ++count; 
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid mark, please re-enter");
            mark = 0; 
        }
    } while ((mark >= 0)&&(mark <= 100));
```

Answer (score -1):

The inner while-loop is then one you're stuck in.

On the one hand, you need an invalid mark to exit,
but on the other, the program rejects invalid marks and keeps on asking until you enter a valid mark.

Result - you're stuck.

Solution:
Change the inner `while` to an `if`, and place the average calculation code and a `System.exit()` in the `if` block.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `System.exit()` *anywhere* unless you really have to. It makes the code even harder to test than it already is. There are much cleaner ways to exit a loop than halting the JVM...